# Detect child node number

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a event listener for clicking and I want to know the position of the node that was clicked

```
function evl(etna) {
    document.addEventListener("click", function (el) {
        alert("You clicked on " + 'the name of element that was clicked or his array code');
    }, false);
};
```

where `etna` is:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("*");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function evl(etna){
    document.addEventListener("click",function (el) {
        var clickedElement = el.target || el.srcElement;
        alert("Link detected a click. Cancellable: "+clickedElement.name);
        for(var i = 0; i < etna.length; i++) {
            if(etna[i] === clickedElement) {
                //i is a position of an element in etna
                break;
            }
        }
      },false);
};
```

<s>You can use `this` which will point to a clicked element.</s>  As to [Phil H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36537/phil-h) IE 8 does not work that way. But anyway, there should be used `.target` or `.srcElement`. And maybe it will be better to get its id. Name attribute is not valid for divs, spans, etc.

But also you are attaching an event to a `document`. And this will point to a document.
Instead of that you should use `el.target || el.srcElement` where `.target/.srcElement` is a pointer to a node where click actually happened.

Also, I do not think you can get index of an element in array (actually, node list) returned by `document.getElementsByTagName("*")` (well, you can get that list and iterate through it in loop and check each element if it is eaqual to `this`). Plus, I have no idea why it could be needed.

Comment: In IE8 and below, the event will not set `this`, so it remains pointing to the global window object: [sitepoint.com](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-this-event-handlers/).

Comment: Possibly. But looks like we both miss a point on which element event is attached :)

Comment: I wont to now his arrey position also like el[10]

Comment: @Karim maybe you can tell why do you need that. As I told, you can go through all elements in `etna` and compare with el.target/el.srcElement, but I do not understand why do you need it. Maybe there is a better way

Comment: @karim see my updated answer. It has a code which should find an index of an element inside etna

Answer (score 0):

Add a loop and set the event listener differently for each item in the `etna` array:

```
function evl(etna){
    for(var i=0; i < etna.length; ++i) {
        (function() {
            var thisNode = etna[i];
            var localval = i;
            etna[i].addEventListener("click",function (el) {
                alert("Link detected a click. Cancellable: "+ thisNode.id + " which is id " + localval );
            },false);
        })();
    }
}
```

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5xDjE/

The function that is immediately called is merely to force the scoping of `thisNode` and `localval`, otherwise all the elements get references to the same variable (javascript scoping is interesting).

I would advise against using the index (scoped via `localval`) because it requires retaining the original array of nodes. Since nodes change over time and javascript does reference counting for you, you want to avoid these kinds of long arrays of nodes.

Note that `this` doesn't always have element that was clicked, in IE8 and below [this points to the global window object](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-this-event-handlers/).