# Javascript - Delegate click event and detect the position of child element(compare with first-child)

Tags: javascript

```
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
```

I find the appropriate way using javascript when I click on one of `child` element. I figure out that element's position(`not coordinate`) such as that element is third children of `parent` element. My asking is same to [Detect child node number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361697/detect-child-node-number?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: If you want pure js, i answered an almost same question an hour ago. Check it **[HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23239388/1906094)**

Comment: @BatuZet Can you give a modify using delegate?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {        
        $('.child').click(function () {
            alert("Position is" + ($(this).index() + 1))
        });
    });
</script>
 <div class="parent" >
        <div class="child">1</div>
        <div class="child">2</div>
        <div class="child">3</div>
        <div class="child">4</div>
        <div class="child">5</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what if the child class is present outside parent and then check your solution how it behaves.

http://jsfiddle.net/AfA4t/159/

Comment: it Will return exact postion inside parent class even if other child class present

Comment: what about outside div's

Comment: it return the same result.

Comment: @Deepak thanks for respond me. It works fine. But in the case, I really need pure javascript

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can use it support ie lower version

```
    <script>
    debugger
    window.onload = function () {
        var childs = document.getElementById('parent').childNodes;

        for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
            childs[i].onclick = function () {
                debugger
                var pos = indexInParent(this);
                alert(pos+1);
            }
        }
    };
    function indexInParent(node) {
        debugger
        var children = node.parentNode.childNodes;
        var num = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            if (children[i] == node) return num;
            if (children[i].nodeType == 1) num++;
        }
        return -1;
    }
</script>
<div class="parent" id="parent">
    <div class="child">
        1</div>
    <div class="child">
        2</div>
    <div class="child">
        3</div>
    <div class="child">
        4</div>
    <div class="child">
        5</div>
</div>
```